# How to describe an index type with generic values in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to describe this interface in `typescript`:

```
abstract class Entity { /*...*/ }
interface List<A extends Entity> { /*...*/ }

// I want the below interface
interface Collections {
  [name: string]: List<A extends Entity>;
}
```

The `Collections` object contains different `List` objects of classes that extend the `Entity` class. So the following code doesn't solve my problem:

```
interface Collections<A extends Entity> {
  [name: string]: List<A>;
}
```

The above interface serves only for one single class `A`, I want it to serve multiple classes extend from `Entity` class.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I caught the idea, this might be the solution?

```js
abstract class Entity { /*...*/ }
class Book extends Entity { title = 'default'; }
class Spoon extends Entity { price = 5; }

interface List<A> { /*...*/ }
interface EntityList extends List<Entity>{}

interface Collections {
  [name: string]: EntityList
}

const t: Collections = {
  'test': [new Book(), new Spoon()]
}

const x = t['test'];
```

If you don't wont to close type you might do this:

```js
interface Collections<T> {
  [name: string]: List<T>
}

const t: Collections<Entity> = {
  'test': [new Book(), new Spoon()]
}
```